# Issue with Java DateUtil

Tags: java, excel

I would like to convert a double to Excel date with Java DateUtil with the following code:

```
        String year = "2017.01.01 00:00:00";
        Date dateY = dateConv1(year); //it converts the string to date
        int serialD = (int)DateUtil.getExcelDate(dateY);
        double dd = Double.parseDouble("84.12237828");
        DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.#####");
        dec.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
        double dd2 = Double.parseDouble(dec.format(dd).replace(",", "."));
        double dd1 = serialD + dd2;
       Date javaDate= DateUtil.getJavaDate((double) dd1);
       String hms = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss").format(javaDate);
```

The result is 2017.03.26 03:56:13 but it is not correct. It should be 2017.03.26 02:56:13 according to the Excel. Can someone suggest me a solution?

Comment: Where does your DateUtil come from? Looks like a timezone/offset problem.

Comment: Smells like a time-zone problem. My first recommendation is always to try the modern `java.time` APIs.

Comment: Your topic has been addressed several times already on Stack Overflow. [Search thoroughly](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+date+double&t=ipad&ia=web) before posting.

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that are now legacy, having been supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310.